# Sagemaker training jobs metrics not shown in monitoring nor cloudwatch/no widget on this dashboard

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sagemaker

Using sagemaker, from previous experience and the official documentation we know it is possible to create plots and visualizations for metrics during training jobs(ex: accuracy, error, etc) however now we cannot see any metrics, this applies to both "Monitoring" tab for the sagemaker jobs and for Cloudwatch, we are capturing the desired metrics in the logs and defined the regular expressions for them, but we cannot see the metrics. Is there any additional configs besides adding the metric definitions(including regex)?

It's important to mention that not even the default metrics(captured automatically by sagemaker, ex: cpu and memory utilization) are shown so I guess it is not related to my metrics(or their regex).

**UPDATE** we found `"cloudwatch:PutMetricData"` was missing in the policy for the `NeptuneSageMakerIAMRole`(that was not originally in the documentation but it was added recently https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/machine-learning-manual-setup.html) and now I can see the metrics listed in cloudwatch however they are still not shown in the "Monitor" tab for the sagemaker job console(before adding PutMetricData to the policy the page was blank, the message was not shown)
[image]

Comment: That should be the only configuration. Referenced the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/training-metrics.html) too. In the training jobs details, did you double-check that the list of metrics and regex are configured? Maybe can show the logs format and the regex in the question, so that we can double-check to make sure the regex works? There are some default metrics that it captures, like resource util. Are these available?

Comment: @RegisterSole thanks,  your comment reminded me to add more details: not even the default metrics are shown